# Reload informations from partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have index that renders a div/table:

index.html.erb

```
<% if session[:user_permissions].include?(75) %>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
      <div>
        <strong>Grupos de Atendimento</strong>
      </div>
      <hr class="name-softphone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <%= render partial: "table" %>
<% else %>
...
```

http://pastebin.com/VyDt6cSX

And the table _table.html.erb:

http://pastebin.com/Wqb7PNg4

So, i got the informations of this table on my controller, but i need to reload the informations on this partial every 30 seconds automatically.

How can i do this, using AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place your table to element with uniq id:

   ```
   <div id="table-polling"><%= render partial: "table" %></div>
   ```
2. Create controller action for long polling and add route for it. Add to it all necessary data for your table generation.
3. Create view for polling action like this:

   ```
   $('#table-polling').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'table' %>");
   ```
4. Add to your js on target page with this table code like this (with your path for created action for long polling):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     setInterval(function () {
       $.ajax('users/<%= current_user.id %>/table_polling');
     } , 30000);          
   });
   ```